Creating a more efficient api request header in Visual Studio and ASP.NET Core MVC and Azure
I created a web app using ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC. Our API is locked down to only accept requests with the correct scope and clientID. We've had some issues with getting access to the API. The only way we've been able to get in is by creating a service that calls the Get/Put/Post. We have to insert a header in every request.
My question: is there a more efficient way to create a header? Perhaps creating it in the program.cs file and passing it that way?
Here is the code we use every time:
using var request = await _downstreamApi.CallApiForUserAsync("DownstreamApi");
var BearerToken = request.RequestMessage.Headers.Authorization;

// add token to httpclient header, to be included when calling the api
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = BearerToken;
//

Here is the rest of the service:
var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("api/AccountCategoryType");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<AccountCategoryType>>();

Lastly, here's what I have inside my program.cs file:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
            .AddDownstreamApi("DownstreamApi", builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();


you could just serve a frontend with Angular, React or Blazor.  (SPA)  Your server would just be serving static files.  (or better yet, serve the frontend from the API server so you can keep everything same-domain.)

@Manny Sanchez What specific issues or errors are being encountered when accessing API
